# Node post method FormData undefined

Tags: node.js, express, form-data

I am sending `FormData` to a node post request, however the `body` is undefined. If I don't use FormData then it works, but FormData does not work.

e.g. the following does not work, i.e. I get `undefined`

```
const order = new FormData();
order.append("name", this.order.name);
await this.storeOrder(order);
```

But the following works:

```
await this.storeOrder({ name: "John"});
```

This is my post method:

```
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

Comment: What is telling console.log("this.order.name:", this.order.name) after your first line?

Comment: Are you sure you want to append `this.order.name`? It looks like a possible error. Also, `FormData` object has no `name` property, causing `order.name` call to return `undefined`.